# PHP array question?

Tags: php

Trying to stop the words `has been entered` from repeating when the array displays its contents when echoed.

Here is the code.

```
echo "$array[$x] has been entered";
```

Comment: Your question obviously doesn't provide enough context. The code you provided only prints once...

Comment: Please clarify what you want.

Comment: I want all the array values to be displayed but i want the words has been entered to only display once. I hope this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo implode(", ", $array) . " has been entered";
```

Answer (score 0):

uh, `echo $array[$x];`?

Answer (score 0):

??

how about

```
echo $array[$x]." has been entered";
```

Answer (score 0):

After your updated comment:

You can use something like

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
  echo $a;
}

echo "has been entered";
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could get your question; try below code:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  // if this is the first item
  if ($key === 1)
  {
    echo "$array[$key] has been entered";
  }
  else
  {
    echo $array[$key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single-quotes rather than double-quotes:

```
echo implode(', ', $array) . ' has been entered';
```